# Attempted to call an undefined method named "request" of class "Zend\Http\Client"

Tags: php, zend-framework

I get the error that is the title, and this is the line of code he is complaining about;

```
$client = new Client($passwordResetUrl, array('timeout' => 30));
$client->setParameterPost(array("username" => $username,
                                "application" => "pw_solcon",
                                "requester" => $requester,
                                "method" => $method));                
$response = $client->request(Client::POST);
if ($response->getStatus() == 200) {
     //do something
}
```

It complains specifically about  `$response = $client->request(Client::POST);`

I looked at the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html) here, but I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Can somebody please help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Zend framework 2 and using documentation for Zend Framework 1

use [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.http.client.html) as your reference.

ZF2 uses `$response = $client->send();`